# Spring Framework upgrade from 5.3.1 to 5.3.14 getting white label error

Tags: java, spring, spring-framework-beans

I was having some problem when trying to upgrade spring framework libraries from 5.3.1 to 5.3.14. When I was using version 5.3.1, there is no white label error page. However, after I upgraded the libraries to 5.3.14, I am getting this error message upon launch:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Jan 04 09:54:57 SGT 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
```

In my logger, I am getting these error messages:

```
[1/4/22 11:40:33:606 SGT] 000000cb ServletWrappe E 

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause dispatcherServlet: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.setContentLengthLong(J)V (loaded from file:/C:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/javax.j2ee.servlet.jar by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@85b881d1) called from class org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse (loaded from file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/backend_war.ear/backend.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-5.3.14.jar by 
com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@c5d284c9[appwar:backend_war]
```

I am using springframework.boot 2.4.0 together with springframework 5.3.14.

[image]
[image]

I have tried the methods [here](https://zetcode.com/springboot/whitelabelerror/) to disable the white label error but it is still showing. Any ideas why is it so? Thanks!

Comment: What version of WebSphere do you use? I think that your version is not compatible with Spring servlet version. `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.setContentLengthLong`

Comment: @Saljack I am using 8.5.5.12 can check with you is it compatible? If no, how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You use too old version of WebSphere 8.5.5 which has Servlet 3.0 which is not compatible with Spring 5.x. Spring 5.x requires Servlet [3.1 or 4.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x#baseline-update). So if you want to use Spring 5 then you have to upgrade your WebSphere to 9 as is described in the upgrading page.

Comment: Sorry Spring 5 as in spring-core-5.3.1 and above? My application is managed to run with spring-core-5.3.1, it only breaks when I tried to upgrade it them 5.3.14

Comment: No Spirng 5.0 >= requires Servlet 3.1 or 4.0. You were just lucky that you have not use any feature from Servlet 3.1 but maybe there is some change in code and which uses `setContentLengthLong` which is there since Servlet 3.1. I strongly recommend you to upgrade your WebSphere or do not use Spring 5 with Servlet 3.0 because similar errors can happen during runtime.